# If ratio of sides of two triangles is constant then the triangles have the same angles

Tags: geometry, triangles, congruences-geometry

If $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle A'B'C'$ are a pair of triangles such that

$$\dfrac{|AB|}{|A'B'|}=\dfrac{|BC|}{|B'C'|}=\dfrac{|AC|}{|A'C'|}$$

then

$$\triangle ABC \sim \triangle A'B'C'$$

I have shown that the converse is true, could I use that to prove the statement in the title?

Answer (score 2):

> If $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle A'B'C'$ are a pair of triangles such that
>   $$\dfrac{|AB|}{|A'B'|}=\dfrac{|BC|}{|B'C'|}=\dfrac{|AC|}{|A'C'|}$$

is equivalent to

> $\triangle ABC$ has the sides $a, b, c$ and $\triangle A'B'C'$ has the sides $a·k, b·k, c·k$ for some $k\in \mathbb R\;\;$

In virtue of the [similarity criterion sss](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry/hs-geo-similarity/hs-geo-triangle-similarity-intro/a/triangle-similarity-review), we obtain, as desired, that $$\triangle ABC\sim \triangle A'B'C'$$

---

Now, why does this work?
Observe, that in virtue of the Law of Cosines

$$\cos{\alpha}=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$$
and 
$$\cos{\alpha'}=\frac{b^2k^2+c^2k^2-a^2k^2}{2bk\cdot ck}=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$$
 And since $f(x)=\cos(x)$ is injective in $(0, \pi)$, we know that $$\color{blue}{\alpha=\alpha'\; \text{ similarly }\; \beta=\beta'\; \text{ and }\; \gamma=\gamma'}$$

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the use of trigonometry?

Comment: There is in fact; see [here](https://www.teachoo.com/4288/1051/Theorem-6.4---Class-10---If-sides-are-in-same-ratio-(SSS)/category/Theorems/)

Comment: I used the Law of Cosines because it's much faster ;)